# Google map - рисование поверх карты

Tags: google-maps-api

Подскажите пожалуйста, как нарисовать что-нибудь поверх карты простенькими стандарнтыми средствами типа DrawCircle. В Google map свои методы типа addCircle, но они привязаны к координатам, а мне этого не надо.

Comment: Можете подробно дать пример как вам надо?

Comment: Ну, я бы хотел нарисовать поверх карты из этого урока http://startandroid.ru/ru/uroki/vse-uroki-spiskom/307-urok-140-google-maps-svoi-obekty-na-karte.html   окружность из этого урока http://startandroid.ru/ru/uroki/vse-uroki-spiskom/312-urok-142-risovanie-prostye-figury-tekst.html    
(не пинайте если глупость спрашиваю, я только учусь)

Answer (score 1):

Примените **[Google Maps API](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/)**. Пример создания кругов на карте Гугл:

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <meta name="viewport" content="initial-scale=1.0, user-scalable=no">
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <title>Circles</title>
    <style>
      /* Always set the map height explicitly to define the size of the div
       * element that contains the map. */
      #map {
        height: 100%;
      }
      /* Optional: Makes the sample page fill the window. */
      html, body {
        height: 100%;
        margin: 0;
        padding: 0;
      }
    </style>
  </head>
  <body>
    <div id="map"></div>
    <script>
      // This example creates circles on the map, representing populations in North
      // America.

      // First, create an object containing LatLng and population for each city.
      var citymap = {
        chicago: {
          center: {lat: 41.878, lng: -87.629},
          population: 2714856
        },
        newyork: {
          center: {lat: 40.714, lng: -74.005},
          population: 8405837
        },
        losangeles: {
          center: {lat: 34.052, lng: -118.243},
          population: 3857799
        },
        vancouver: {
          center: {lat: 49.25, lng: -123.1},
          population: 603502
        }
      };

      function initMap() {
        // Create the map.
        var map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map'), {
          zoom: 4,
          center: {lat: 37.090, lng: -95.712},
          mapTypeId: 'terrain'
        });

        // Construct the circle for each value in citymap.
        // Note: We scale the area of the circle based on the population.
        for (var city in citymap) {
          // Add the circle for this city to the map.
          var cityCircle = new google.maps.Circle({
            strokeColor: '#FF0000',
            strokeOpacity: 0.8,
            strokeWeight: 2,
            fillColor: '#FF0000',
            fillOpacity: 0.35,
            map: map,
            center: citymap[city].center,
            radius: Math.sqrt(citymap[city].population) * 100
          });
        }
      }
    </script>
    <script async defer
    src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?key=YOUR_API_KEY&callback=initMap">
    </script>
  </body>
</html>
```

Источник **[Circles of Google Maps API](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/examples/circle-simple)**.

Пример создание треугольника:

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <meta name="viewport" content="initial-scale=1.0, user-scalable=no">
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <title>Polygon Arrays</title>
    <style>
      /* Always set the map height explicitly to define the size of the div
       * element that contains the map. */
      #map {
        height: 100%;
      }
      /* Optional: Makes the sample page fill the window. */
      html, body {
        height: 100%;
        margin: 0;
        padding: 0;
      }
    </style>
  </head>
  <body>
    <div id="map"></div>
    <script>

      // This example creates a simple polygon representing the Bermuda Triangle.
      // When the user clicks on the polygon an info window opens, showing
      // information about the polygon's coordinates.

      var map;
      var infoWindow;

      function initMap() {
        map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map'), {
          zoom: 5,
          center: {lat: 24.886, lng: -70.268},
          mapTypeId: 'terrain'
        });

        // Define the LatLng coordinates for the polygon.
        var triangleCoords = [
            {lat: 25.774, lng: -80.190},
            {lat: 18.466, lng: -66.118},
            {lat: 32.321, lng: -64.757}
        ];

        // Construct the polygon.
        var bermudaTriangle = new google.maps.Polygon({
          paths: triangleCoords,
          strokeColor: '#FF0000',
          strokeOpacity: 0.8,
          strokeWeight: 3,
          fillColor: '#FF0000',
          fillOpacity: 0.35
        });
        bermudaTriangle.setMap(map);

        // Add a listener for the click event.
        bermudaTriangle.addListener('click', showArrays);

        infoWindow = new google.maps.InfoWindow;
      }

      /** @this {google.maps.Polygon} */
      function showArrays(event) {
        // Since this polygon has only one path, we can call getPath() to return the
        // MVCArray of LatLngs.
        var vertices = this.getPath();

        var contentString = '<b>Bermuda Triangle polygon</b><br>' +
            'Clicked location: <br>' + event.latLng.lat() + ',' + event.latLng.lng() +
            '<br>';

        // Iterate over the vertices.
        for (var i =0; i < vertices.getLength(); i++) {
          var xy = vertices.getAt(i);
          contentString += '<br>' + 'Coordinate ' + i + ':<br>' + xy.lat() + ',' +
              xy.lng();
        }

        // Replace the info window's content and position.
        infoWindow.setContent(contentString);
        infoWindow.setPosition(event.latLng);

        infoWindow.open(map);
      }
    </script>
    <script async defer
    src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?key=YOUR_API_KEY&callback=initMap">
    </script>
  </body>
</html>
```

Источник: **[Polygon Arrays of Google Maps API](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/examples/polygon-arrays)**.

Пример создания прямоугольника:

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <meta name="viewport" content="initial-scale=1.0, user-scalable=no">
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <title>Rectangles</title>
    <style>
      /* Always set the map height explicitly to define the size of the div
       * element that contains the map. */
      #map {
        height: 100%;
      }
      /* Optional: Makes the sample page fill the window. */
      html, body {
        height: 100%;
        margin: 0;
        padding: 0;
      }
    </style>
    <script>

      // This example adds a red rectangle to a map.

      function initMap() {
        var map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map'), {
          zoom: 11,
          center: {lat: 33.678, lng: -116.243},
          mapTypeId: 'terrain'
        });

        var rectangle = new google.maps.Rectangle({
          strokeColor: '#FF0000',
          strokeOpacity: 0.8,
          strokeWeight: 2,
          fillColor: '#FF0000',
          fillOpacity: 0.35,
          map: map,
          bounds: {
            north: 33.685,
            south: 33.671,
            east: -116.234,
            west: -116.251
          }
        });
      }
    </script>
  </head>
  <body>
    <div id="map"></div>
    <script async defer
    src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?key=YOUR_API_KEY&callback=initMap">
    </script>
  </body>
</html>
```

Источник: **[Rectangles of Google Maps API](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/examples/rectangle-simple)**.

Пример создания круга, как символа, с svg:

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <meta name="viewport" content="initial-scale=1.0, user-scalable=no">
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <title>Predefined Marker Symbols</title>
    <style>
      /* Always set the map height explicitly to define the size of the div
       * element that contains the map. */
      #map {
        height: 100%;
      }
      /* Optional: Makes the sample page fill the window. */
      html, body {
        height: 100%;
        margin: 0;
        padding: 0;
      }
    </style>
  </head>
  <body>
    <div id="map"></div>
    <script>
      // This example uses a symbol to add a vector-based icon to a marker.
      // The symbol uses one of the predefined vector paths ('CIRCLE') supplied by the
      // Google Maps JavaScript API.

      function initMap() {
        var map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map'), {
          zoom: 4,
          center: {lat: -25.363882, lng: 131.044922}
        });

        var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
          position: map.getCenter(),
          icon: {
            path: google.maps.SymbolPath.CIRCLE,
            scale: 10
          },
          draggable: true,
          map: map
        });

      }
    </script>
    <script async defer
    src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?key=YOUR_API_KEY&callback=initMap">
    </script>
  </body>
</html>
```

Источник: **[Predefined Marker Symbols of Google Maps API](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/examples/marker-symbol-predefined)**.

Пример создания звезды, как символа, с svg:

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <meta name="viewport" content="initial-scale=1.0, user-scalable=no">
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <title>Custom Marker Symbols</title>
    <style>
      /* Always set the map height explicitly to define the size of the div
       * element that contains the map. */
      #map {
        height: 100%;
      }
      /* Optional: Makes the sample page fill the window. */
      html, body {
        height: 100%;
        margin: 0;
        padding: 0;
      }
    </style>
  </head>
  <body>
    <div id="map"></div>
    <script>
      // This example uses SVG path notation to add a vector-based symbol
      // as the icon for a marker. The resulting icon is a star-shaped symbol
      // with a pale yellow fill and a thick yellow border.

      function initMap() {
        var map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map'), {
          zoom: 4,
          center: {lat: -25.363882, lng: 131.044922}
        });

        var goldStar = {
          path: 'M 125,5 155,90 245,90 175,145 200,230 125,180 50,230 75,145 5,90 95,90 z',
          fillColor: 'yellow',
          fillOpacity: 0.8,
          scale: 1,
          strokeColor: 'gold',
          strokeWeight: 14
        };

        var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
          position: map.getCenter(),
          icon: goldStar,
          map: map
        });
      }
    </script>
    <script async defer
    src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?key=YOUR_API_KEY&callback=initMap">
    </script>

  </body>
</html>
```

Источник: **[Custom Marker Symbols of Google Maps API](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/examples/marker-symbol-custom)**.

Пример создания стрелки, как символа, с svg:

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <meta name="viewport" content="initial-scale=1.0, user-scalable=no">
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <title>Arrows (Symbols)</title>
    <style>
      /* Always set the map height explicitly to define the size of the div
       * element that contains the map. */
      #map {
        height: 100%;
      }
      /* Optional: Makes the sample page fill the window. */
      html, body {
        height: 100%;
        margin: 0;
        padding: 0;
      }
    </style>
  </head>
  <body>
    <div id="map"></div>
    <script>
      // This example adds a predefined symbol (an arrow) to a polyline.
      // Setting offset to 100% places the arrow at the end of the line.

      function initMap() {
        var map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map'), {
          zoom: 6,
          center: {lat: 20.291, lng: 153.027},
          mapTypeId: 'terrain'
        });

        // Define a symbol using a predefined path (an arrow)
        // supplied by the Google Maps JavaScript API.
        var lineSymbol = {
          path: google.maps.SymbolPath.FORWARD_CLOSED_ARROW
        };

        // Create the polyline and add the symbol via the 'icons' property.
        var line = new google.maps.Polyline({
          path: [{lat: 22.291, lng: 153.027}, {lat: 18.291, lng: 153.027}],
          icons: [{
            icon: lineSymbol,
            offset: '100%'
          }],
          map: map
        });
      }
    </script>
    <script async defer
    src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?key=YOUR_API_KEY&callback=initMap">
    </script>
  </body>
</html>
```

Источник: **[Arrows (Symbols) of Google Maps API](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/examples/overlay-symbol-arrow)**.

Пример анимации символа:

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <meta name="viewport" content="initial-scale=1.0, user-scalable=no">
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <title>Animating Symbols</title>
    <style>
      /* Always set the map height explicitly to define the size of the div
       * element that contains the map. */
      #map {
        height: 100%;
      }
      /* Optional: Makes the sample page fill the window. */
      html, body {
        height: 100%;
        margin: 0;
        padding: 0;
      }
    </style>
  </head>
  <body>
    <div id="map"></div>
    <script>
      // This example adds an animated symbol to a polyline.

      function initMap() {
        var map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map'), {
          center: {lat: 20.291, lng: 153.027},
          zoom: 6,
          mapTypeId: 'terrain'
        });

        // Define the symbol, using one of the predefined paths ('CIRCLE')
        // supplied by the Google Maps JavaScript API.
        var lineSymbol = {
          path: google.maps.SymbolPath.CIRCLE,
          scale: 8,
          strokeColor: '#393'
        };

        // Create the polyline and add the symbol to it via the 'icons' property.
        var line = new google.maps.Polyline({
          path: [{lat: 22.291, lng: 153.027}, {lat: 18.291, lng: 153.027}],
          icons: [{
            icon: lineSymbol,
            offset: '100%'
          }],
          map: map
        });

        animateCircle(line);
      }

      // Use the DOM setInterval() function to change the offset of the symbol
      // at fixed intervals.
      function animateCircle(line) {
          var count = 0;
          window.setInterval(function() {
            count = (count + 1) % 200;

            var icons = line.get('icons');
            icons[0].offset = (count / 2) + '%';
            line.set('icons', icons);
        }, 20);
      }
    </script>
    <script async defer
    src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?key=YOUR_API_KEY&callback=initMap">
    </script>
  </body>
</html>
```

Источник: **[Animating Symbols of Google Maps API](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/examples/overlay-symbol-animate)**. Дополнительно смотрите документацию Google Maps API для создания **[фигур](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/shapes)** и **[символов](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/symbols)** на картах Гугл.

Вы спрашиваете:

> И ещё напоследок, для полного счастья - как добавить тескт?

Возможно так:

```js
function initialize() {

  var frrlanser_marker = {
    strokeColor: '#FF0000',
    strokeOpacity: 0.8,
    strokeWeight: 2,
    fillColor: '#FF0000',
    fillOpacity: 0.35,
    radius: 60 * 100
  };

  var latlng = new google.maps.LatLng(64.1791647,-51.7768493);
  var myOptions = {
    scrollwheel: false,
    zoom: 10,
    center: latlng,
    mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP
  };

  var map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById("map"),
    myOptions);
  var fill_color_val = '#3888ff';

  var latitude = 64.1791647;
  var lontitude = -51.7768493;

  var myLatLng = google.maps.LatLng(latitude, lontitude);

  var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
    position: latlng,
    map: map
  });

  // Add circle overlay and bind to marker
  var circle = new google.maps.Circle({
    map: map,
    radius: 3200, // 10 miles in metres
    fillColor: fill_color_val,
    strokeColor: '#FFFFFF',
    strokeWeight: 2,
    fillOpacity: 1,
  });
  circle.bindTo('center', marker, 'position');

  marker.setVisible(false);

  var labelText = "1";
  var myOptions = {
    content: labelText,
    boxStyle: {
      border: "none",
      textAlign: "center",
      fontSize: "10pt",
      width: "50px"
    },
    disableAutoPan: true,
    pixelOffset: new google.maps.Size(-25, -5),
    position: latlng,
    closeBoxURL: "",
    isHidden: false,
    pane: "floatPane",
    enableEventPropagation: true
  };

  var ibLabel = new InfoBox(myOptions);
  ibLabel.open(map);

}
```

```html
<div id="map"></div>
```

Comment: Тут https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/android-api/shapes?hl=ru написано что гугломапсовские окружности круглы только на экваторе, а хотелось бы везде..

Comment: Смотрите главу в указанной вами документации "Круги". В приведённом примере кода сообщается: .center(new LatLng(37.4, -122.1)). Вы можете устанавливать ваши данные в эти элементы. Здесь нет указаний/ограничений только для экватора. Вероятно вы ошибаетесь.

Comment: Ну как, там же написано "Поскольку проекция Меркатора, используемая Maps API, проецирует сферу на плоскую поверхность, на карте это будет отображаться в виде практически идеального круга в случае расположения возле экватора, и в виде объекта все менее круглой формы (на экране) по мере удаления от экватора."
А ответ на свой вопрос нашел здесь https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34243870/draw-canvas-on-google-maps-v2 - это невозможно. Печалька.

Comment: Вот пример карты Гренландии с кругами - это довольно далеко от экватора https://docs.google.com/document/d/1Yp4RR6R_02d-RNYop0bm17pLG_USnQ4wat-0AOPGutw/edit?usp=sharing

Comment: Не забудьте установить ваш ключ для Гугл карт.

Comment: А есть ли в этом api функция преобразования координат в метры? Чтобы нарисовать круг с центром не в текущем местоположении, а метрах в 100 восточнее. Поискал - не нашел, хотя должна бы быть.

Comment: С помощью этого инструмента http://itouchmap.com/latlong.html определите требуемые вам координаты и установите там круг.

Comment: Спасиб. И ещё напоследок, для полного счастья - как добавить тескт? Хочу написать что-нибудь  в нарисованной с Вашей помощью окружности, Пока нашел только маркер с текстом, который всплывет  при нажатии на него.

Comment: Возникла еще одна проблемка - мои круги и прочие фигуры рисуются не совсем поверх - они перекрываются текстом на карте (описанием объектов) и линиями трафика. Как бы "приподнять" свои фигуры? Вроде есть параметр zIndex, но с его помощью можно поднимать свои объекты над другими своими объектами, а над объектами карты - нет.

Comment: Проверьте следующую документацию: https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/shapes#circles ++ https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/examples/overlay-simple ++ https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/customoverlays . Надеюсь что это поможет.